# Remove SharePoint Workflow Template programmatically

Tags: templates, sharepoint, workflow

When using SharePoint Designer 2013, under "Workflows" option in Navigation pane I can view and remove workflow templates.

[image]

Is it possible to do the same programatically (preferably via PowerShell)?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I just faced this same problem and determined that deleting the folder within the hidden "Workflows" list in the site is how to remove the template:

```
$web = get-spweb $SiteUrl
$templates = $web.WorkflowTemplates | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Send Reminder Email"}
if ($templates.Count -gt 0) {
    $web.Lists["Workflows"].RootFolder.SubFolders.Delete("Send Reminder Email")
}
```